# Install extension in Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, mcrypt

I'm trying to install the extension mcrypt in xampp and windows.

Version: Apache / 2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL / 1.1.0h PHP / 7.2.8

I copied the extension ( php_mcrypt.dll ) to C: \ xampp \ php \ ext \ . Nevertheless, I get the error at the command: php artisan serve:

```
Php_mcrypt.dll (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll (The specified module was not found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_mcrypt.dll.dll (The specified module was not found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mcrypt.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\ php_mcrypt.dll (The specified module was not found.), C:\xampp\php\ext\ php_php_mcrypt .dll.dll (The specified module was not found.)) in Unknown on line 0 Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

What's going on?

Comment: from your error message: >> php_php_mcrypt.dll.dll. Are you sure that's the dll's name?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use Laravel. The problem was that I had an outdated version installed

Comment: use comment section for this

Comment: This is not an answer this is a comment.